# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^6-2x^2}{xy^2\left(2y^3+x\right)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^6-2x^2}{xy^2\left(2y^3+x\right)}$$

This is not a homogeneous ODE and I checked it is not first order linear differential equation (even after reversing the fractions and trying to solve for $x$ it is not in that form). I tried writing the equation in the form of

$$(y^6-2x^2)dx-xy^2(2y^3+x)dy=0$$
But it is not an exact equation and I also couldn't find integral factor for it. I don't know which method I have to use to solve the equation.

Comment: Hint: change variable to $z = \frac{y^3}{x}$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks! Can you please explain how did you recognized the substitution $z=\frac{y^3}x$ works?

Comment: First, if you move the $y^2$ in RHS's denominator to LHS, everything can be expressed as a simple power of $y^3$. This suggest a change of variable to $w = y^3$. After that, RHS becomes a homogeneous rational function in $x,w$. This suggest another change of variable to $z = \frac{w}{x}$.

Comment: After @achille hui's good hint and explanation, you have a separable equation which will give you $x$ as a function of $z$. Don't go further.